# Continuously fetching data to update state

Tags: react-redux

For a part of my React App, I want to live update my data. Currently, I have a fetchPosts action who's reducer returns something like

```js
{
  searchQuery1: {
    // any data I need
  },
  searchQuery2: {
    // any data I need
  }
}
```

where each searchQuery corresponds to a rendered `<Column />` component that displays fetched data.

Now if I want to live update this data by basically sending requests to my backend in a loop and waiting for data to change and handling it accordingly, would I just put a `setInterval()` function inside of a  `componentDidMount()` function within my `<Column />` component that calls an action for handling the live data updating?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you.But if you set a `setInterval()` function,that may raise a problem.If the network of your app block,then that may cause the problem that you post useless requests.So I think you may need set a threshold inside your `setInterval()` function.The function of the threshold is that if the app did't finish its last request,then it will not post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
class Column extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.refreshData, 1000);
  }
  refreshData = () => {
    // dispatch your action action here
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // use intervalId to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
 }
  render() {
    return <div>{/* Your code goes here*/}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the interval in componentWillUnmount.

I hope this helps you